# Errors and warnings with cassandra and cqlsy

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

When I run cassandra i get the output like this:

```
D:\STUDIA\cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.9\bin>cassandra
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

and when i type cqlsh:

```
D:\STUDIA\cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.9\bin>cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Nie mo\xbfna nawi\xb9za\xe6 po\xb3\xb9czenia, poniewa\xbf komputer docelowy aktywnie go odmawia")})
```

it says that
"Can not
make connections because the target computer is actively refusing it"

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that Cassandra is not running. You will need to check the Cassandra `system.log` to get an idea of the cause.

It may have failed to start or shutdown. It isn't possible to know why without looking at the logs. Cheers!